# Upload files to service

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, multipartform-data, kaltura

I'm trying to adapt [Kaltura API](http://www.kaltura.com/api_v3/testme/client-libs.php) so it would work with Windows 8.1 application, and I am having problems with this function:

```
private void PostMultiPartWithFiles(HttpWebRequest request, KalturaParams kparams, KalturaFiles kfiles)
{
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;

        // use a memory stream because we don't know the content length of the request when we have multiple files
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] buffer;
        int bytesRead = 0;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in kparams)
        {
            sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + param.Key + "\"" + "\r\n");
            sb.Append("\r\n");
            sb.Append(param.Value);
            sb.Append("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
        }

        buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        memStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, FileStream> file in kfiles)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            FileStream fileStream = file.Value;
            sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + file.Key + "\"; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(fileStream.Name) + "\"" + "\r\n");
            sb.Append("Content-Type: application/octet-stream" + "\r\n");
            sb.Append("\r\n");

            // write the current string builder content
            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // write the file content
            buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)fileStream.Length))];
            bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }

        request.ContentLength = memStream.Length;

        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        // write the memorty stream to the request stream
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        buffer = new Byte[checked((uint)Math.Min(4096, (int)memStream.Length))];
        bytesRead = 0;
        while ((bytesRead = memStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
            requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        requestStream.Close();
        memStream.Close();
 }
```

I have tried something like this:

```
private void PostMultiPartWithFiles(HttpWebRequest request, KalturaParams kparams, KalturaFiles kfiles)
{
    using (request)
    {
        string boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
        MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent(boundary);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in kparams)
         {
             Stream fileStream = await new StringContent(param.Value).ReadAsStreamAsync();
             StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(fileStream);
             streamContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"" + param.Key + "\"");
             content.Add(streamContent);
         }
        foreach (var file in kfiles)
        {
            StorageFile storageFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(file.Value.Path);
            var randomAccessStream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync();
            Stream stream = randomAccessStream.AsStreamForRead();
            StreamContent streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"" + file.Key + "\"; filename=\"" + file.Value.Name + "\"");
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            content.Add(streamContent, "fileData", file.Value.Path);
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working. It says that `fileData` is not attached. I haven't really worked with those *web things* before, so maybe I'm doing it all wrong.

Comment: What if you add `Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary`?

Comment: Wait, what exactly is your purpose here? Are you rewriting the first block of code to the second for some reason? Because the second is missing any code that actually _uses_ the created `MultipartFormDataContent` object.

Comment: @Nyerguds Where exactly to add that? How can I use the created `MultipartFromDataContent`? I really don't know, how to rewrite first given code so it would work in windows 8.1 app

Comment: Better question... what exactly doesn't work in the first code? The fact it's a Windows 8.1 app shouldn't matter much; it's still just c#.

Comment: As for the `MultipartFormDataContent`, eh, you added that, in your own code... so if you have no idea how to use it, it's rather odd you chose to use it.

Comment: @Nyerguds Problem with first code is that it isn't compiling, because some things in metro apps are different, for example, `HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest`. I'm adding `MultipartFromDataContent` because after reading about those things, it seems that you have to use it to upload files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got how to do it. My code looks like this:

```
byte[] concatinated = null;
string boundary = string.Empty;
boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
byte[] buffer;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("--" + boundary + "\r\n");
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param1 in kparams)
{
    sb.Append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + param1.Key + "\"" + "\r\n");
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    sb.Append(param1.Value);
    sb.Append("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");
}
buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());

byte[] fileBytes = null;
byte[] filebytes2 = null;
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, StorageFile> file in kfiles)
{
    StorageFile storageFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(file.Value.Path);
    using (IRandomAccessStreamWithContentType stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync())
    {
        fileBytes = new byte[stream.Size];

        using (DataReader reader = new DataReader(stream))
        {
            await reader.LoadAsync((uint)stream.Size);
            reader.ReadBytes(fileBytes);
        }
    }
    filebytes2 = BuildByteArray("fileData", storageFile.Name, fileBytes, boundary);

    concatinated = new byte[buffer.Length + filebytes2.Length];
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, concatinated, 0, buffer.Length);
    System.Buffer.BlockCopy(filebytes2, 0, concatinated, buffer.Length, filebytes2.Length);
    buffer = new byte[concatinated.Length];
    concatinated.CopyTo(buffer, 0);
}
```

And

```
private byte[] BuildByteArray(string name, string fileName, byte[] fileBytes, string boundary)
{
        // Create multipart/form-data headers.
        byte[] firstBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(
            "--{0}\r\n" +
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\"\r\n" +
            "\r\n",
            boundary,
            name,
            fileName));

        byte[] lastBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Format(
            "\r\n" +
            "--{0}--\r\n",
            boundary));

        int contentLength = firstBytes.Length + fileBytes.Length + lastBytes.Length;
        byte[] contentBytes = new byte[contentLength];

        // Join the 3 arrays into 1.
        Array.Copy(
            firstBytes,
            0,
            contentBytes,
            0,
            firstBytes.Length);
        Array.Copy(
            fileBytes,
            0,
            contentBytes,
            firstBytes.Length,
            fileBytes.Length);
        Array.Copy(
            lastBytes,
            0,
            contentBytes,
            firstBytes.Length + fileBytes.Length,
            lastBytes.Length);

        return contentBytes;
  }
```

And then I use it like this:

```
HttpRequestMessage requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
requestMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(concat);
requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data");
requestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("boundary", boundary));
var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The idea and second function I got from [this article](http://eren.ws/2013/10/20/http-multipartform-data-upload-in-windows-store-apps-boredom-challenge-day-16/).